# Forward method is fired at page loading time not at pretty link clicking time

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

While debugging, I have noticed that the method `myBean.forward()` get fired when I am getting forwarded to the home.xhtml page containing the pretty-link below and that even before clicking on the pretty-link (i.e. product label) :

home.xhtml

```
<pretty:link target="_self" mappingId="#{myBean.forward(product, true)}"  >
       <f:param value="#{vo.product.hash }" />        
       <ice:outputText value="#{vo.product.label}"/>
</pretty:link>
```

pretty-config.xml

```
<url-mapping id="myApp/seller/addProduct">
        <pattern value="/myApp/seller/addProduct/#{fooBean.productHash}" />
        <view-id value="/pages/seller/products/addProduct.xhtml" />
        <action>#{myBean.myMethod}</action>          
</url-mapping>
```

MyBean.java

```
public class MyBean{
    //source code omitted
    public String forward(Product p, boolean pretty){

        if(prettyLink)  
           return "myApp/seller/addProduct";    
        else 
           return fooBean.getContextService().getBaseURL()+"/myApp/seller/addProduct/"+p.getHash();

  }
}
```

Could someone please explain me why this occurs and how to avoid it (i.e. the method should be fired only when the link is being clicked). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be binding a JSF ValueExpression to a `<pretty:link>` component, but ValueExpressions are for this component are evaluated at page rendering time.

This is because the `<pretty:link>` component is designed to create a URL that is rendered in the browser to allow bookmarking, without calling back into JSF to execute a method. This means you cannot dynamically change the value of a `<pretty:link>` at runtime.

You would be better off using an `<h:commandLink>` (which executes an action method on postback, when clicked, not when rendered), then you can perform server-side navigation from your action method since that appears to be the behavior you are expecting.

Basically, `<pretty:link>` is designed to do the exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I did end-up doing. I had to use <h:commandLink/> instead in order to circumvent this issue. Thanks for your feed-back :)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out :)